# HOSTS mapping not working as expected

Tags: networking, localhost, web-development, hosts-file

I'm running a local Webmatrix configuration which uses IISExpress as webserver.

For convenience's sake, I have configured my remote development setup (`http://godrul1.gopagoda.com/`) to `http://localhost:80`, through the windows HOSTS file.

So, as expected from the setup, when I point to `http://godrul1.gopagoda.com/`, it should route to `http://localhost:80`.

But it's giving a 404 error.

I know that my local webserver (Webmatrix/IISExpress) isn't malfunctioning because pointing straight to `http://localhost:80` works.

What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: If it's giving you a 404 server then you're getting a proper reply from a web server. So, as far as the `HOSTS` file (and DNS) is concerned, everything might be just fine. Maybe your local server is simply not configured to answer `GET` requests for that Host.

Comment: Just to expand on what Oliver said, when you go to localhost, you are getting the "default" website.  If your iis is configured to uses virtual hosts, when you go to godrul1.gopagoda.com, iis will look for a matching virtual host with that name.  If it isn't there, it will 404.

Comment: +1 for @oliver above... This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Can you look at my [`web.config`](http://pastebin.com/LLR5Vrag) and tell me if it's configured incorrectly?

Comment: @Paul Can you look at my [`web.config`](http://pastebin.com/LLR5Vrag) and tell me if it's configured incorrectly?

Comment: PS: It used to work without doing much except adding the mapping in `HOSTS` file in the past, for a similar (previous) setup.